# python pip gives: "no such option: -r"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

So I just freshly installed python3.7. I've used python 2 for a long time but I needed python 3 for a 
specific module.

So I tried to install the requirements.txt via `py -m pip install -r requirements.txt` but when I do, I get the following error:

```
Usage:
  D:\Python37-32\python.exe -m pip <command> [options]

no such option: -r
```

I dont think my install is broken as I get the same error with python 2 (`python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`)

pip is also in my path but I use it with `py -m pip` because I have both python versions 2 and 3 installed on my system and need to make sure I use the correct pip with the correct python version

Why can't I install the requirements.txt and am I getting this error instead?

Comment: Can you try --requirement instead of -r? I think py may be treating '-r' as an option for it instead of pip.

Comment: @PaulaThomas Doesnt work, It gives the same error

Comment: Also which os are you using?

Comment: I think it's windows, because it says "python.exe"

Comment: Yes indeed, it windows 10

Comment: Can you show us, what is inside `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Its just one module: `pycrypto==2.6.1`

Comment: Did you by any chance modifiy `pip` itself?

Comment: @sashaaero no, I just clean installed python3 and the first thing I did was try that requirements.txt. I did click the custom installation and unchecked the `ascociate py files with python` because I want them to be ascociated with python2 but I left the rest on default. and I also tried to install the requirements on python 2 but it didnt work there either

Comment: For dummies like me, `pip -r requirements.txt` gives this error message when you forget `install`. Facepalm emoji.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I didnt have the environments setup correctly.

I restarted my pc what I forgot to do after installing and the command did work after that.

Answer (score 7):

Try using:

`python -m pip install -r req.txt`

Some times using "py" doesn't work.

Comment: ... 1. If "py" wouldnt work then it wouldnt give me that error it would just say `'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` 2. `py` is for python 3 and `python` is for python 2 I have both installed and if I were to use `python` I would install the requirements on python 2 not on python 3

Comment: Hello there, Are you using anaconda by any chance?

Comment: No, I'm not using anaconda.

Comment: novun i have only python 3.5 on my pc and this command is working fine for me. the error message you provided is a message we get if that environment variable is not available. py is not available on your comp. please try "python" "https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/"

Comment: Again, I also have python2 installed on my pc. this means that when I type `python` it triggers python2 and not python3